# Unable to delete elements from DOMDocument?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to delete `tr` elements from the users list admin page Using the DOMDocument  but the problem is it didn't delete all the `tr` elements in the page and i don't know why.

```
function profile_callback( $html )
{
    $profile_dom = new DOMDocument;
    $profile_dom->loadHTML( $html );
        foreach ($profile_dom->getElementsByTagname( 'tr' ) as $h_tag){
                $h_tag->parentNode->removeChild( $h_tag );
            }

    return $profile_dom->saveHTML();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had solved it by using the `iterator_to_array()` function.

```
function profile_callback( $html )
{
    $profile_dom = new DOMDocument;
    $profile_dom->loadHTML( $html );
        foreach (iterator_to_array($profile_dom->getElementsByTagname( 'tr' ) as $h_tag)){
                $h_tag->parentNode->removeChild( $h_tag );
            }

    return $profile_dom->saveHTML();
}
```